# trying to show data from two tables with WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query, which works:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT sid, name, last_name, tuition
FROM students 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM payments 
WHERE payments.forMonth = 'May'
AND students.sid = payments.sid)
```

However, when I try to add a couple columns from the payments table, the query fails:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT students.sid, students.name, students.last_name,
students.tuition, payments.amount, payments.forMonth
FROM students payments
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM payments
WHERE payments.forMonth =  'Apr'
AND students.sid = payments.sid)
```

I've tried this with an inner join in the top-half of the query, but that generated wrong results.
Is there a way to do this?

(The reason for the EXISTS condition is that I'll have a toggle on the filter form that will show either payments made or payments not made.)

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma between "students payments" after the FROM?

Comment: Sorry for the typo.  Though, without the comma, an actual error results.  I'm just getting wrong results.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer query uses an inner join and passes its forMonth information to the subquery. Think of it this way, how could the exist statement be useful, if it does not know which month the outer query is looking at.

```
SELECT DISTINCT students.sid, students.name, students.last_name,
students.tuition, payments.amount, payments.forMonth
FROM students
 INNER JOIN payments ON students.sid = payments.sid
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT * 
FROM payments p2 
WHERE p2.forMonth =  payments.forMonth )
And payments.forMonth = 'Apr'
```

Comment: Hi @sukebe7 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: This works for EXISTS but the INNER JOIN returns an empty result set when using NOT EXISTS.  Though I may not need to display data from the payments table with NOT EXISTS, it makes switching the query easier.